# What security setting is preventing Remote PowerShell 2.0 from accessing UNC paths

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

This is just crazy, I am starting on PowerShell. And of course I need to do Admin work remotely.

A simple

```
dir \\server\share\folder
```

Just refuses to work, I get this error

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path '\\server\share\folder' because it does not exist.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\server\share\folder:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

To me it is pretty obvious it is an access rights issue. And we do have a domain here at the company. I am logged in to the server, with the exact same user account, on VNC and I can see the UNC path. But whenever I try to just copy a file from my desktop with the remote connection. It just won't work!!!!

I can do many other things so I am positive I am connected.

Comment: in a dos shell command 'dir \\server\share\folder' give no error??

Comment: That is correct. Maybe I should write "dir \\MyServer\MyShare\MyFolder". I did find out I need to setup CredSSP, I did and I still get a timeout followed by Enable-WSManCredSSP : This command cannot be executed because the setting cannot be enabled. This can happen if no network connection is present.

Comment: By now, I used gpedit.msc to allow for fresh credentials on BOTH computers. I set the fresh credentials policy and I use the `enable-wsmancredssp -role client -delegatecomputer computer1.domain.com` and `enable-wsmancredssp -role server` commands. For status I execute 'Get-WSManCredSSP' and I get
**The machine is configured to allow delegating fresh credentials to the following target(s): wsman/computer1.domain.com,wsm
an/*.domain.com. This computer is configured to receive credentials from a remote client computer.** I can't find anytheing else to do and it is still not working!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To get this to work, you must configure both your local and remote computers.

**On the remote server**, run the following command:

```
 Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role server
```

You'll know things are confgured correctly if you run the `Get-WSManCredSSP` cmdlet and get the following output:

> The machine is not configured to allow delegating fresh credentials.
>   This computer is configured to receive credentials from a remote client computer.

**On your local computer**, from an Administrative PowerShell prompt, you need to allow credential delegation in PowerShell. Run the following command:

```
 Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer <REMOTE_COMPUTER_NAME>
```

You can enable all servers by using * for `REMOTE_COMPUTER_NAME`.

You'll know this is configured correctly when you run Get-WSManCredSSP and get the following output:

> The machine is configured to allow delegating fresh credentials to the following target(s): wsman/REMOTE_SERVER_NAME
>   This computer is not configured to receive credentials from a remote client computer.

**On your local machine**, update Group Policy to allow your credentials to be delegated to the remote server.

1. Open gpedit.msc and browse to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Credentials Delegation.
2. Double-click "Allow delegating fresh credentials with NTLM-only Server Authentication".
3. Enable the setting and add the build server to the server list as WSMAN/BuildServerName.  (You can enable all servers by entering WSMAN/*.)

Then, when you need to run your command on the remote server, **you can't use any of the *-PSSession commands** because CredSSP can't use cached credentials. You have to start the session using `Invoke-Command`, and use CredSSP as the value to the Authentication parameter, like so:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { # remote commands here } `
               -ComputerName <REMOTE_COMPUTER_NAME> `
               -Authentication CredSSP `
               -Credential <USERNAME>
```

Comment: Great answer and lots of good info thanks! Unfortuantely, I still have a problem. I've made the changes in the group policy but when I run the following in an elevated PS window: "Enable-WSManCredSSP -role Client -DelegateComputer d-vasbiz01 -force" I get the following error: "Enable-WSManCredSSP : This command cannot be executed because the setting cannot be enabled" any ideas?

Comment: I found it! Problem was within the group policy editor I needed to prefix the name of the server I'm delegating to with "wsman/". This is as stated by the answer, but I missed it! Many thanks for the answer.

Comment: I did not have to do the "group policy" steps just the enable "client" and enable "server" roles on the correct computers.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell also uses Internet Explorer security settings on running remote scripts.

I have found that, for whatever machine you are trying to have run a remote script, if I add the unc path of the remote machine to my trusted intrAnet sites, I can run scripts then (assuming my execution policy in posh is set to remotesigned...."set-executionpolicy remotesigned").

I do a ton of administration for multiple servers with and without SQL, and I've never done anything with Enable-WSManCredSSP.