# Powershell Enable-WSManCredSSP

Tags: powershell

I need to execute a remote command and pass credentials, so I've followed the answer here: [What security setting is preventing Remote PowerShell 2.0 from accessing UNC paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362057/what-security-setting-is-preventing-remote-powershell-2-0-from-accessing-unc-pat)

Problem is, I get the following error
    **Enable-WSManCredSSP : This command cannot be executed because the setting cannot be enabled**

I've checked event logs on both servers but can see nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! Problem was within the group policy editor I needed to prefix the name of the server I'm delegating to with "wsman/". This is as stated by the answer I referred to in my question, but I missed it! Many thanks for the answer.