# Powershell Get-WmiObject Access is denied

Tags: powershell, tfs

I have a Powershell script containing the following line:

```
$package = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $TargetServer -Filter ("Name='{0}'" -f $ApplicationName)
```

I followed the steps on this answer in order to enable Powershell Remoting between the servers: [remoting security steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362057/what-security-setting-is-preventing-remote-powershell-2-0-from-accessing-unc-pat)

When I run the script from the Powershell ISE (in an elevated admin window) then I get the following error:

```
Get-WmiObject : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
At line:1 char:14
+ Get-WmiObject <<<<  win32_bios -computername d-vasbiz01
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WmiObject], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

I need to be able to run the script in the ISE so that I can troubleshoot other problems.

Can anyone please suggest what I need to do to fix this security error?

Comment: I just want to verify - you've tried it from a standard window as well as one with elevated privileges, right?

Comment: I notice that you're talking about remoting.  Are you trying to double-hop at any point?

Comment: No, the VM hosting the client and server both in the same domain - actually on the same physical host.

Comment: OK, my mistake - this doesn't work when run from TFS either. Regardless of how the code is run I get the security exception. Do I need to enable a trust between machines or something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to pass credentials to the Get-WmiObject cmdlet.

I found the answer here:[Powershell Masters](http://powershellmasters.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/powershell-and-remote-wmi.html)

Comment: Can you help me to give it more detail?. I'm stuck really. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't quite get this one because I'm passing the exact same credential as I'm using to call the script or even just run the command directly in a shell, but sure enough it starts working for me when the credentials is explicitly provided.

Answer (score 0):

After guessing for a WHILE, cached credentials were my problem.

Open windows credentials manager:

rundll32.exe keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr

Delete all cached entries.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Rob Bowman's answer, you can either gather the credentials up front, or when running the command.

- Up front (preferable, as you can re-use it for future Get-WmiObject commands:

  ```
  $creds = get-credential

  $package = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $TargetServer -Filter ("Name='{0}'" -f $ApplicationName) -credential $creds
  ```
- Inline:

  ```
  $package = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $TargetServer -Filter ("Name='{0}'" -f $ApplicationName) -credential (get-credential)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to grant that user WMI permissions.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771551(v=ws.11).aspx

Local  / domain admin should have that by default.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30159266)

Answer (score 0):

**Additional Consideration: MS Patching**

Our new system builds were failing to isntall an application which maks a WMI call when it starts to check something with the server application. I created a test WMI script and found that WMI calls worked everywhere in the environment but the new builds. Hence the fix was to install the MS patches to match everything else and the issue resolved itself (it may be a patch that came out July 2021).