# Get-WmiObject : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) on only local machine

Tags: windows, powershell, permissions, wmi

I'm getting the below error message when queriying the local server using the hostname:

```
PS C:\Users\user1> Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service" -ComputerName ServerA
Get-WmiObject : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WmiObject], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

The same query if working if I'm using the servers IP addresses. I can ping ServerA and use that IP address but for some reason the hostname isn't working.

This is also working:

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service" -ComputerName localhost
```

I have started PowerShell as administrator so it's using my permission. I'm administrator on all our servers. I have checked DCOM permissions and WMI namespace permissions according to this guide:
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1140794/get-wmiobject-access-is-denied-(exception-from-hre)

"Enable Distributed COM on this computer" is also enabled.

So hostname nor FQDN isn't working, but localhost and the IP address is working. It's the same IP address I'm getting if I ping ServerA. I have also tried using the below query with Domain Admin permission, same error message:

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service" -ComputerName ServerA -Credential $cred
```

Seems like a DNS or loopback problem?

Any idea why this isn't working? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the Local Host is the same machine as the IP you are using?  IP addresses of machines will change on most networks if DHCP is enabled.

Comment: "*So hostname nor FQDN*", what you showing are friendly names. A FQDN has dots in the middle, did you try that? Did you check setting the credentials in the command, see: [Powershell Get-WmiObject Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968210/powershell-get-wmiobject-access-is-denied)?

Comment: @jdweng This server has multiple IP addresses. We're using them within a Failover Cluster. Let's say the cluster name is PT-TC. If I ping PT-TC it will reply with the Cluster IP address of that specific role. We're failing over the role which contains the IP. So I can access the WmiObject via the roles IP address and localhost but not the actual role name.

Comment: You must have more than one domain.  Try host name with the domain : https://kb.wisc.edu/sscc/page.php?id=105379

Comment: No WMI in PowerShell Core. CIM is available.

Comment: There has to be something blocking the loopback connection. Or it's a DNS problem. ServerA in the below query is in fact the failover cluster role name. If I do an ipconfig I can see that the server has both the local IP and the cluster IP from the failover role.

Query:
```Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service" -ComputerName ServerA -Credential $cred```

Solved the issue by checking if the cluster role is running on the same server as the one performing the script. In that case I will omit ```-ComputerName ServerA -Credential $cred``` so the script is running completely local