# Executing a remote SSIS package via Powershell

Tags: powershell, ssis

I'm a Powershell newbie and am trying to use [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/10/11/remote-ssis-package-execution-with-powershell-2-0.aspx) article to create a way for another user to kick off an SSIS package on a remote server.

The Powershell code I'm using is:

```
$pass = convertto-securestring "myPassword" -asplaintext -force
$mycred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "myUsername",$pass

invoke-command -computername myServer -scriptblock { dtexec.exe /File "d:\myPath.dtsx" } -credential $mycred
```

Even though I've tried passing my credentials in Powershell, the SSIS package doesn't seem to be executing with them and is executing as an Anonymous user.  The package is failing validation for a number of reasons -

- The package can not connect to a remote file that requires permission to access (I have permission but the Anonymous User does not).  The user that I would like to have run this script does have permission to the folder.
- The SQL Server login is failing.  I tried forcing a SQL user in the connection details of the package but that doesn't seem to have worked.

Can I use change the Powershell code to use Windows Authentication?  How do I execute the SSIS package using those permissions?

Answer (score 1):

you need to enable CredSSP first (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362057/what-security-setting-is-preventing-remote-powershell-2-0-from-accessing-unc-pat)), and use `invoke-command -Authentication Credssp`