# installing remotely from computer A to server B and the installer UNC path from server C

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop, remote-server

Hi When I run this powershell code my powershell just hangs

```
Set-Content "\\$remote_computer\users\bkoo004\downloads\test\installme.bat" -value 'START "installing" "S:\npp.6.3.3.Installer.exe" /S'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remote_computer -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {Start-Process 'c:\users\bkoo004\downloads\test\installme.bat' -Wait}
```

But if run this code

```
Set-Content "\\$remote_computer\users\bkoo004\downloads\test\installme.bat" -value 'START "installing" "C:\users\user\downloads\npp.6.3.3.Installer.exe" /S'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remote_computer -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {Start-Process 'c:\users\bkoo004\downloads\test\installme.bat' -Wait}
```

I can install fine.. I am thinking that its some UAC or other security that is trying to block my install from a UNC path(drive S). Can anyone please help? Is it because double hop?

Comment: Is the `S:` a network drive on the server?

Comment: I mapped the S: drive in server B even without mapping my I can't install from a UNC path

Comment: This is the so-called [double-hop problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242248/double-hop-access-to-copy-files-without-credssp)