# Get-Item cmdlet on remote fileshare not returning result with invoke-command

Tags: powershell

I run a simple Get-Item cmdlet to get the below result :

```
(Get-Item -Path \\priam\coste\ZEDMB5T-Intransit-report\* -Include DAILYREPORT_TES_MSS_20190426_*.XLS).name
```

[image]

I try the same using an invoke-command, but it does not give me anything :

```
invoke-command -ScriptBlock {(Get-Item -Path \\priam\coste\ZEDMB5T-Intransit-report\* -Include DAILYREPORT_TES_MSS_20190426_*.XLS).name} -computername localhost -Credential Get-Credential
```

There is nothing wrong with the credentials since it does work for the below command :

```
invoke-command -ScriptBlock {"testing"} -computername localhost -Credential Get-Credential
```

[image]

I have access to the path as well :

```
 Get-Acl -Path \\priam\coste\ZEDMB5T-Intransit-report | Format-List -Property *
```

[image]

I am running the powershell ISE as an administrator, as seen in the title bar :
[image]

I am using a recent version of PS :
[image]

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: when i run your command [modified for my files] in a normal PoSh shell, the Invoke-Command fails with an `Access is denied.` error message. when i run it in an elevated shell [run as administrator] it works.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I am running as administrator as well. But it does not return anything for me.

Comment: i am lost, then. it works for me in an elevated `run as administrator` shell. note that i am NOT talking about using an admin account ... but running an elevated shell.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Yes, i right-click on the "Windows Powerhell ISE" app in the start menu and choose "run as administrator". Did you try with a file share on a remote system, as opposed to a local path?

Comment: i only have one system, so that is not possible. i did try it with a shared dir and got the same result as my other tests. so you may have found the differentiator. [*grin*] here's hoping someone with more experience - and a net to test on - drops by.

Comment: Looks like standard second-hop issue. Do you have CredSSP configured for PowerShell connections?

Comment: @PetSerAl No, i don't. I tried "Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role "Client" ", but i get an error "The DelegateComputer parameter is mandatory when the Role parameter value is Client.". I think it's an Azure fileshare, how would a DelegateComputer apply here?

Comment: I tried Enable-WSManCredSSP with the DelegateComputer parameter, but i get an error "Enable-WSManCredSSP : This command cannot be executed because the setting cannot be enabled." Then i tried "winrm set winrm/config/client/auth @{CredSSP="true"} ". I got an "Access is denied." error.

Comment: This is the double-hop issue. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813002/unable-to-access-unc-paths-in-powershell-remote-session

Comment: @Scepticalist Understood. But looks like the only solution is CredSSP and i am not able to enable it as explained in previous comments.