# How can I call a Function, inside of a Function, inside of Invoke-Command ScriptBlock?

Tags: powershell, function, logging, scripting, invoke-command

I have been racking my brain over this and scouring the internet for an answer, but I can't seem to find anything for my specific situation.  I have created a set of Functions that help me add/remove users and groups from the local "Remote Desktop Users" group on Win2016 Servers remotely.  By themselves, they work fine, but I am trying to add them to a menu script that I am developing so other admins can use them without having to run them manually.

The problem I am having is that in my script setup, I have created groups of logging functions that I am trying to use inside of my Add/Remove User functions, which needs to be used inside of an Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock.  However, this is the error that I get:

```
The term 'Write-GreenConsole' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Write-GreenConsole:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    + PSComputerName        : SERVER01
```

Here are two of the functions am trying to get to work together.  The first one is the logging function, the second one is the Add/Remove function.

```
function Write-GreenConsole ( $Details ) {
    $today = Get-Date -UFormat %d%b%Y
    $LogPath = "\\Network_Path\RDP_Logs_$today.log"
    $LogDate = Get-Date -UFormat "%D %T"
    $LogLevel = "INFO"
    $Results =  Write-Output "[$LogDate] [$LogLevel] [$ServerName]: $Details"
    $Results | Out-File -FilePath $LogPath -Append
Write-Host "[$LogDate] [$LogLevel] [$ServerName]: $Details" -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black
}
```

```
function Get-RDPGoupMembers ( $svrName ) {
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $svrName -ScriptBlock { 
    Write-GreenConsole "[ Group members for Server $env:COMPUTERNAME =" (Get-LocalGroupMember -Group 'Remote Desktop Users').Name "]"
  }
}
```

The "$svrName" variable comes from the main script based on user inputs from the menu.  Please let me know if you need any more details.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A remotely executing script block shares no state with the caller, so the script block you're passing to [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) `-ComputerName ...` doesn't know about the caller's `Write-GreenHost` function.

Therefore, you must pass the *function definition* to the script block and *recreate the function there*:

```
function Get-RDPGoupMembers ($svrName) {
  $funcDef = ${function:Write-GreenConsole} # aux. variable that stores the function body.
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $svrName -ScriptBlock { 
    ${function:Write-GreenConsole} = $using:funcDef # recreate the function
    Write-GreenConsole "[ Group members for Server $env:COMPUTERNAME =" (Get-LocalGroupMember -Group 'Remote Desktop Users').Name "]"
  }
}
```

Note:

- The above focuses just on recreating your function as-is.

  - Separately - and this aspect is independent of whether a function is involved or not - because your function happens to access a *network location*, more work is needed to work around the so-called [double-hop problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ashleymcglone/powershell-remoting-kerberos-double-hop-solved-securely); one solution, which involves passing explicit credentials and using them to map an aux. drive in the remote script block, is demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48692809/45375). Note that you needn't actually *use* that aux. drive: Once it is mapped, UNC paths to the same resource will start to work.
- `${function:Write-GreenConsole}` is an example of *namespace variable notation*: on *getting* the value, the function's *body* is returned; on *setting* it, the function created (or its existing body is redefined). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375) for background information.
- Note the use of an *aux. variable*, `$funcDef`, to store the function body in the caller's scope, which is then referenced in the remote script block via the [`$using:` scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables#using-local-variables).

  - The reason is that trying to combine `$using:` with namespace variable notation currently (as of PowerShell (Core) 7.3.x) causes *parser errors* with function names containing `-` and is *quietly ignored* with function names that don't; that is, `${using:function:Write-GreenConsole}` does *not* work.
  - Arguably, however, it *should*, especially given that it *does* work with `Start-Job`. See [GitHub issue #20422](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20422).

Comment: Good Morning and thank you for the response!  Both the "namespace variable notation" and the "aux. variable" methods seem to work, but now I get an error relating to permissions on the share folder as follows:

`Access to the path '\\Network_Path\RDP_Logs_03Oct2023.log' is denied.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
    + PSComputerName        : SERVER01`

I even tried a network folder that has full control set for "Everyone" with the same results.

Comment: @FlyingSubieSTi, I've added the information about the double-hop problem to the answer. Given that a solution to the latter is unrelated to recreating the function - you'd face the same problem whether or not you're trying to access the network resource  via a function - I do not think it is worth spelling out the solution _here_, and that the link to an answer with a solution is sufficient. Please see my update.