# Powershell commands not working via PSRemote

Tags: powershell, module, remote-server, windows-installer

I'm having some issues with trying to install various programs via powershell. This is an example (trimmed down) of the component of the module I've built:

```
Function TEST-INSTALL-Scripts
{
    Param($basepath,$Arguments)

    $command = @"
cmd.exe /C msiexec /package `"$basepath`" $Arguments
"@
    Invoke-Expression -Command $command
}
```

When I try to invoke it via

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {TEST-INSTALL-Scripts -Basepath $basepath -Arguments $args}
```

The command doesn't seem to do anything so I tried using a PSRemote tab to try to get some more details and I used this command:

```
$basepath = "\\$Server\d$\Files\Install\3rd Party\SQL Server Native Client\sqlncli_x64.msi"
$Arguments = '  /quiet /passive'
TEST-INSTALL-Scripts -basepath $basepath -Arguments $Arguments
```

And I get a response back saying the file cannot be accessed or its not a valid file.

> T h i s   i n s t a l l a t i o n   p a c k a g e   c o u l d   n o t   b e   o p e n e d .     V e r i f y   t h a t   t h e   p a c k a g e   e x i s t s   a n d   t h a t   y o u   c a n   a c c e s s   i t ,   o r   c o n t 
>   a c t   t h e   a p p l i c a t i o n   v e n d o r   t o   v e r i f y   t h a t   t h i s   i s   a   v a l i d   W i n d o w s   I n s t a l l e r   p a c k a g e .

When I RDP onto the machine itself, the exact same command works without any issue.

My research is pointing toward this being a double hop issue, but short of copying the file to the machine, is there a way of dealing with this that isn't a nightmare?

Comment: `-ScriptBlock {TEST-INSTALL-Scripts -Basepath $basepath -Arguments $args}` - that won't work; see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36328690/478656 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/40247384/478656 and linked questions

Comment: Also why are you calling `cmd.exe` inside of Powershell `cmd.exe /C msiexec /package \`"$basepath\`" $Arguments` -> `msiexec /package \`"$using:basepath\`" $Arguments`

Comment: @BenH I'm using cmd because there are some legacy tools I also need to install using cmd and I find it easier to keep the same flow (you are only seeing a trimmed version)

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I did notice that and fixed it, but the bigger problem is that it throws the permission error when I use PSRemotetab which is essentially the same as a PSSession. I started getting the same error when I fixed passing the Args.

Comment: Then .. duplicate of [Double hop access to copy files without CredSSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242248/double-hop-access-to-copy-files-without-credssp) because your question is "I don't want to have to deal with security, please can I skip it?" and the answer is "if you could skip it, we could all skip it, and if that were an option, the existing answers wouldn't be a nightmare because nobody would answer with nightmare options if there were easy options"

Comment: fair enough... I did get a workaround built that is minimal which I'll post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to build a minimal workaround that I put in just before the remote call where I pass the install path. I also built a function to make it easier to manager but I put an example IF statement here (I built Get-InstallerLocal which does the same copy based on type)

```
        If($installPath.StartsWith("\\"))
        {
            $DeployPath = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {$env:TEMP}
            $drive=(Get-Item $DeployPath).PSDrive.Name
            $localpath = $DeployPath
            $DeployPath = $DeployPath.Replace("$($drive):","\\$machine\$drive$")
            If(!(Test-Path "$DeployPath\3rd Party\Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable"))
            {
                Copy-Item -Path "$installPath\3rd Party\Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable" -Destination "$DeployPath\3rd Party\Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable\" -Force -Recurse
            }
            If($ODBCDriver){Get-InstallerLocal -installPath $installPath -deployPath $DeployPath -Type "SQL Driver"}
            $installPath = $localpath
        }
```